# Iterate on an array of int to display them as String in Java

Tags: java

The display method `public static String display(int[] values)` will receive an array of int values and return a String in the following format:

```
subscript[0] = ____  
subscript[1] = ____  
subscript[2] = ____  
subscript[3] = ____
```

A line should be generated for each value in the array. Recall that \n is a newline escape sequence

*I'm having trouble with this problem, can anyone show me how it is done with arrays?*

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this yourself, SO is here to help you and not to write your code.
Nevertheless, here is the result:

```
public static String display(int[] values) {

    if (values == null) return;

    for (int val : values) { // loop through all items in array

        System.out.println(val); // print value with ending \n to console/stdout

    }

}
```

Instead of the System.out.println you could also use an [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

(Sorry for bad format, I was using my smartphone)